# Document detection/scanner using image segmentation

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection

Most of the references I see on internet to detect the document is using edge detection to get the four edges and get the intersection of the lines. Finally get the corner points. For example [document detection](https://dropbox.tech/machine-learning/fast-and-accurate-document-detection-for-scanning).

But I read something about we can use image segmentation method to have a better result. If I get the segmentation for example by neural network. After that how can I proceed? I can get edges from this segmentation? Or I can directly the polygons or corner points from the segmentation?
Thank you.

Comment: you could train a network to directly predict the corner points, if you like. lots of ways to approach this. try some and compare.

Comment: If the background is well contrasted, both edge detection and (adaptive) binarization will work. If the contrast is low, both will fail, as will other forms of segmentation. In such cases, your may try and improve the situation using the knowledge that the outline is a quadrilateral (detect long straight edges, possibly forming corners, and try to reassemble them). Neural nets will be of little help. Overlapping pages will wreak havoc.